# Add SwipeToRefresh to RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Have activity page with following code:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mainList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F0F2F5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

On my main activity.kt file, I have the following code but I am unsure where i need to put listenings etc. as I didn't write this part of the code;

```
package com.example.what2do_v2

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageButton
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
import com.example.what2do_v2.Adapter.TaskAdapter
import com.example.what2do_v2.Model.TaskResponse
import com.example.what2do_v2.Service.ApiClient
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val apiService by lazy {
        ApiClient.create()
    }


    private var taskData : ArrayList<TaskResponse> = arrayListOf();

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val searchbutton:ImageButton=findViewById(R.id.searchbutton)
        searchbutton.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySearch::class.java))
        }

        val saves:ImageButton=findViewById(R.id.saves)
        saves.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySaves::class.java))
        }

        val settings:ImageButton=findViewById(R.id.settings)
        settings.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySettings::class.java))
        }
        loadData();
    }

    private fun loadData(){
        var data = apiService.getMainData();

        data.enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<TaskResponse>> {

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ArrayList<TaskResponse>>,
                response: Response<ArrayList<TaskResponse>>
            ) {

                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    taskData = response.body()!!;
                    displaydata();
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<TaskResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("-----------------", t.toString())
            }
        })
    }

    private fun displaydata(){
        var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mainList);
        var adapter = TaskAdapter(this, taskData);
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }
}
```

I'm really struggling where to add additional "SwipeRefreshLayout" code into the above. I have tried to follow each example on stackflow, but can't seem to understand where the appropriate places to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the `SwipeRefreshLayout` & assign a refresh listener in your `onCreate()` like this:

```kotlin
val swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout)

// load data on swipe refresh.
swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener { loadData() }

// Disable the refreshing after data load
swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
```

Comment: Amazing - when i add in just this code, it refreshes, but the refresh icon stays - how do i add in stop refresh when its refreshed?

Comment: @user19437536 Updated the answer to include that as well :)

Comment: That was so simple - other tutorials have been so complicated, thanks!

Comment: small and convenient answer